# Can not move out of borrowed content in struct getters

Tags: rust

Its not clear why a borrowed reference is not able to make a call to the function.

```
Standard Error

   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
warning: unused variable: `a`
  --> src/main.rs:23:9
   |
23 |     let a = Astruct::new(Atype::TypeA, 100);
   |         ^ help: consider prefixing with an underscore: `_a`
   |
   = note: #[warn(unused_variables)] on by default

error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
  --> src/main.rs:13:14
   |
13 |         Some(self.aType)
   |              ^^^^^^^^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0507`.
error: Could not compile `playground`.

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

```
enum Atype {
    TypeA,
    TypeB,
}

struct Astruct {
    pub aType : Atype,
    pub aVal : i32,
}

impl Astruct {
    pub fn getType(&self) -> Option<Atype> {
        Some(self.aType)
    }

    pub fn new(aType: Atype, aVal: i32) -> Astruct {
       Astruct { aType: aType,
                 aVal: aVal}
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = Astruct::new(Atype::TypeA, 100);

    //println!("Type: {} Val: {}", a.aType, a.aVal);
}
```

Comment: Because you are making a move operation in the function, you can't move anything from a borrowed content. It would be something like moving gpu to your computer from some else's computer which is borrowed*.  [Copying/Cloning](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c957e1d912ad36678997dc54085d1811) would work but  i suggest you to understand the concept and costs first

Comment: It's not clear why you wouldn't just let callers borrow the value - [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=93287a443e29e742e8c92fe06a2fbf44)

Comment: Thanks for the input.

Comment: Can you provide some link explaining these concepts with examples?

Comment: [The Rust Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/) maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to move `aType` out of the struct `Astruct` and return it from the method `getType`. However, `getType` only borrows `Astruct`  (as you can see from `&self`). Since `getType` doesn't own `Astruct`, it can't move anything out of it.

Depending on what you are trying to do, you have some options:

1. Make `Atype` derive `Copy` and `Clone`, such that it can copy `aType`. To me this seems like what you wanted to do:

```rust
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
enum Atype {
    TypeA,
    TypeB,
}
```

2. Make `getType` consume `Astruct`:

```rust
pub fn getType(self) -> Option<Atype> {
  Some(self.aType)
}
```

3. Make `getType` return a reference to `Atype`

```rust
pub fn getType(&self) -> Option<&Atype> {
  Some(&self.aType)
}
```

Each of these options has its pros and cons.